# How to fix 'Lossing Stream Before End of Stream in Gstream-0.10'

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer-0.10

I have streamed video via vlc player over rtsp and then I have displayed this video via gstreamer-0.10. However, While vlc was streaming video over rtsp, I suddenly lost stream in the first minute of stream before end of stream.

I have used following pipeline:

**GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! 
gstrtpjitterbuffer  ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! videorate  !  xvimagesink 
sync=false**

I have got following output:

**rtpjitterbuffer.c:428:calculate_skew: delta - skew: 0:00:01.103711536 too big, reset skew**

rtpjitterbuffer.c:387:calculate_skew: backward timestamps at server, taking new base time

Got EOS from element "pipeline0".

Execution ended after 59982680309 ns.

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
gst_rtspsrc_send: got NOT IMPLEMENTED, disable method PAUSE

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. I have used **rtspt://...** instead of rtsp://... to enforce TCP instead of UDP.

gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location= **rtspt://127.0.0.1:8554/test** ! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false